# teamcity is not executing msbuild command

Tags: visual-studio-2010, teamcity, msdeploy

I have a configuration in teamcity that package and deploys. I am using the following to package and deploy on a remote server

```
/M /P:Configuration=%env.Configuration% /P:DeployOnBuild=True
/P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=%env.TargetServer%/MsDeployAgentService /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /P:Username=%env.username% /P:Password=%env.password%
```

It is not doing any thing just building the project. Any idea what I am missing here. Process that makes a package is missing from build. Validating Web Deploy package/publish. plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [You're deploying it wrong! TeamCity, Subversion & Web Deploy](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_11.html) series. My suspicion is that either Web Deploy is not configured correctly on the server (i.e. service not started) or that your credentials are incorrect. Try going through the steps in the series above and getting the basics to work work leaving TeamCity until the very end. Get it deploying from Visual Studio then the command line and work from there.

Comment: I tried using command prompt to package it first and got the error "error MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project.". Following your post regarding Why the target “Package” does not exist in the project" checked everything. but all seems fine to me. Using the following to run command ----C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>msbuild Z:\publish\it\cl\cl.vbproj /T:Package /P:Configuration=Deploy-dev. Any idea what I am missing and doing wrong here

Comment: Solved the problem by following the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found............By copying web and web application folder to build machine

Answer (score 0):

Here is my deployment string for our TeamCity publish:

```
/t:ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication /p:OutDir=..\..\..\build\Framework.Production\bin\;WebProjectOutputDir=..\..\..\build\Framework.Production\
```

I believe the part you need is `/t:ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication`