# Trying to get TFS 2012 to publish site

Tags: tfsbuild

I am trying to get my TFS server to build and then publish my application - building it is not a problem but deploying it yields not results.

Quick review of my build config:

- Workspace: Active $/Path/to/solution Build Agent Folder: $(SourceDir)
- Process: Build Any CPU | Staging

  - Ms Build args:  /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://{host}:8172/msdeploy.axd /p:MsDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:username= /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True

The build agent is using a service account which I have defined as a IIS Manager on the site.  Within the project properties I have defined the site name within the Staging configuration (I have been following this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxJUhIQfzlA)

Is the problem I'm having around the user authentication and I should specify the username and password within the MsBuild Args?

Within the MSBuild log, it makes no mention of publishing the application in anyway.  Where am I going wrong?

Edit: In an attempt to get a resolution to my problem, I have included some screenshots of the build config - a username and password has been defined with admin privileges on the server

[image: General Tab]
[image: Trigger]
[image: Workspace]
[image: Build Defaults]
[image: Process]

Comment: Actually, having asked the question I thought I would try it out and specify the username and password within the Build arguments - no joy there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, needed to install [Web Deploy v3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30436) So glad I got to the bottom of that!  If you have also stumbled across this post, you may also find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found/6413635#6413635) of some use.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting just the server name in the MsDeployServiceUrl param. That is the way mine are and they work fine. Everything else is the same as yours.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:DeployIISAppPath="Default Web Site/xyz" /p:MsDeployServiceUrl="webservername"  /p:username="def" /p:password="ghi"
```

Comment: Sorry, no joy with that - are the quotes required? or are you trying to highlight those areas?

Comment: I have the quotes in the string in the build definition. Is there any error messages or anything? Can you do a manual publish from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Just out of interest, having no tests but having test projects - would this stop publishing the site?