# MsBuild to build and create a deployment package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I was trying to use the following command to build my solution, but that was giving me an error saying `MSBuild target package not found`

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe"
>   "C:\Users\FullPath\SolutoinName.sln" **/T:Build;package**
>   /p:Configuration=DEBUG /p:OutputPath="obj\DEBUG"
>   /p:DeployIisAppPath="/bidmc-defaul" /p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0

I have tried [MSBuild target package not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found) but that did not help, then I removed **package** from target and ran the command and it was successful

Then I ran the following command to create a package zip

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe"
>   -verb:sync -source:package="C:\Users\Full Path\Website\obj\Debug_PublishedWebsites\defaul_Package\myPackage.zip"
>   -dest:auto,computerName=localhost -allowUntrusted=true

Now this says `object of type package and path cannot be created, the zip package could not be loaded, could not find part of the path`

**Update**

---

fix to my first command to create package. I was giving my solution name SolutoinName.sln, I replaced it with my main project in solution myproject.csproj, with corresponding paths. That resolved my first error.

> now second error has changed to "the applicatoin pool that you are
>   trying to use has the managedRuntimeVersion property set to v4.0 the
>   application required 4.5"

How should I address this, just install .NET 4.5 on build machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're attempting to build a VS2012.NET 4.5 or higher solution with MSBuild 4.0. That's supported, provided you install the [full .NET 4.5 Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) and the required SDK's and targeting packs for [VS 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh487283.aspx), [VS 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn250998) and [more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2015/07/06/a-complete-list-of-microsoft-sdks-for-developers.aspx).

Alternatively, you can upgrade to [MSBuild 2013 v12.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) (for VS 2013 solutions support) or [MSBuild 2015 v14.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) (VS 2015).

Comment: Just incase somebody else comes across this for VisualStudio 2017 (C# 5.0+), msbuild v14 does not create publish package but msbuild v15 found in the visual studio directory (as opposed to msbuild) will create packages.. Took me 2 days to fix this for a new TeamCity server. Only affects web application though which made it even more difficult to pint point. No errors or warning provided.. at all.

Comment: @ppumkin I'm struggling for few days but not able to build package (or publish) from MVC (.net framework 4.6.1, VS 2017) project. Is it possible to get the full command line arguments/switches you used to package the project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `VisualStudioVersion` to 11 on the MSBuild call.

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IIS Manager to upgrade the .NET Framework version assigned to your app pool (or change your project properties to downgrade the .NET Framework version your web application targets).