# MSBuild missing target WebPublish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am trying to publish a website at our CI server.

For some reason target WebPublish works when building with MSBuild 12.0 but not with MSBuild 14.0.

I can test it with following command: `msbuild My.Web.csproj /t:WebPublish`
It works with 12.0. MSBuild 14.0 gives error:
Build FAILED.

```
R:\My.Web\My.Web.csproj" (WebPublish target) (1) ->
R:\My.Web\My.Web.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "WebPublish" does not exist in the project.

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

I have Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 installed. Is there something else I have to install in the CI server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install "Web Developer Tools". You can do it from "Programs and Features" and repairing Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into this problem currently, there are some alternative solutions [posted on the following stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found)

The thing that fixed it for me was the "Web" and "Web Applications" folders found in the MSBuild directory for the version of visual studio that matched what I built my project in. In my case this was

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0