# Task VSBuild failed. This caused the job to fail

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines

I am getting following error while Automating my build. I am using Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO) and Visual Studio 2015.

```
[error]System.Exception: Task VSBuild failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
```

Please find the attached images for details which I have mentioned while creating Automate Build Definition.

[Build Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qrl2.png)

[Repository Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSMq1.png)

I don't understand why the `Task VSBuild failed. This caused the job to fail.` error is coming.

Comment: Can you queue the build with "system.debug" variable set to "true" and then share the entire logs?

Comment: Hi,I have set "system.debug" variable to "true" and following is the entier log:

Comment: Hi,I have set "system.debug" variable to "true" but getting same error: Build FAILED. 1 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)
 ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
 ##[section]Finishing task: VSBuild
 ##[error]System.Exception: Task VSBuild failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
 ##[error] at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
 ##[section]Finishing Build

Comment: There isn't any other fail logs? It indicates that msbuild exits with code 1, there should be some msbuild error during the build.

Comment: Yes. One more error is there: "packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.1.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets (338, 5)
The "VerifyVersionCompatibility" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.1.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure
.Fabric.BuildTasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 
'file:///C:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.1.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.BuildTasks.dll' 
or one of its dependencies.."

Comment: When does this error occur? In the second build step or third? It would be much better if you can share the entire logs from the build start to end.

Comment: If you using a custom msbuild logger which throws LoggerException, it might be the reason for this.

Comment: I am getting this error in the 3rd build setp. And now getting below error:  "The target "Package" does not exist in the project."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild target package not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found)