# Error MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines

I am facing this issue while Continuous Integration from Visual Studio Team Services.

I have followed stackoverflow link:   [MSBuild target package not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found).

- I have installed .net Framework 4.5 on Build server machine.
- Installed web deployment tool too.
- Created "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0" folders in "C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft" and pasted "Web" and "WebApplication" folder from DEV machine (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0) and past into build server machine on newly created folder path i.e C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0

But still I am facing the same issue.

NOTE: I have given configuration details on below stackoverflow lin: 
[Task VSBuild failed. This caused the job to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822013/task-vsbuild-failed-this-caused-the-job-to-fail).

Comment: Finally, issue is resolved. Above stackoverflow link solution is correct. Only missing point from my side is, I did all configutaiton only on one port. We need to do all this configuration on the all 5 ports. When I did this, problem is solved automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild target package not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar Issue . I Added below lines to my .csproj file and it worked

```
 <PropertyGroup>
     <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
     <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)       </VSToolsPath>
 </PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />

 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

for more info check below answer
[error MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project file named MVCWebUIComponent.csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803777/error-msb4057-the-target-package-does-not-exist-in-the-project-file-named-mvc)

[MSBuild target package not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found)