# building/publishing .net web application using team city and web deploy without installing visual studio

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, webdeploy

Hi I am trying to build and deploy a web application using team city and web deploy. I got it all working the way i wanted it on my dev machine with visual studio 2015, however when trying to set it up on a server windows server i keep getting the build error :-

MSB4057: The target "WebPublish" does not exist in the project

I have installed MSBuild tools 2015 and also Visual Studio isolated shell 2015.

what are the other things i need to install to get this to work when installing visual studio is not an option ?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same problem today. In case anyone else reads this post and has the same error, there are several solutions [posted on the following stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607428/msbuild-target-package-not-found)

The thing that fixed it for me was copying "Web" and "Web Applications" folders found in the MSBuild directory for the version of visual studio that matched what I built my project in, over to the build server (keeping the same path).

In my case this was

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0